# How to create a swift project with react-native components?

Tags: swift, react-native

I tried to follow the instruction on here: https://gist.github.com/boopathi/27d21956fefcb5b168fe

The instruction is somewhat dated with respect to how fast new react-native builds are pushed.

I fixed some of the obvious issues in the instruction (change lib.ReactKit.a to libReact.a, etc...).

I was able to compile the swift project and bring up the simulator.  However, the red screen of death showed up with the following msg:
    Unable to execute JS call: __fbBatchedBridge is undefined

Any insights or general direction to how to create a swift project with react-native would be appreciated.

Comment: Would this be related?  https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5090

Answer (score 1):

After looking through multiple ways of creating a swift project, the following method worked for me:

1)  Follow the instruction here (use the swift version): https://github.com/davidyaha/react-native/blob/master/docs/EmbeddedAppIOS.md

2)  If your build ran into a red screen of death with "Could not connect to development server".  Paste the following lines into your Info.plist file under your swift project:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Detailed discussion of the reasoning is here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/304

The above steps will allow you to see the react-native component in a swift project.